# PostgreSQL pg_ctl register error under Windows 7

Tags: windows, postgresql, service

Under Windows 7, PostgreSQL 9.3.2, I'm trying to register as a service a second instance of PostgreSQL on the same server, using a different port number and data directory. The 2nd cluster was successfully created with the initdb command, under C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data2.

When I run the following pg_ctl register command from C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin, I get an error message:

```
pg_ctl register -N postgresql9.2_2nd_cluster -U "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data2" -S auto -o "-p 5431"

pg_ctl: could not open service manager
```

I googled this, but without much success.

Comment: Are you a local administrator?

Comment: Right on, a_horse_with_no_name ! I had to execute that command with administrator privileges on my DOS console. Thanks!

Comment: Postgres does not run on DOS.

Comment: @SébastienClément I think you mean "command prompt" or "cmd.exe" ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This error:

> pg_ctl: could not open service manager

would suggest that you're probably on a UAC-enabled machine, and you're running in a non-admin console.

When you launch your console from Start->Command Prompt, right click on it and choose "Run as Administrator".

Comment: That's it.  Run the command prompt or terminal as Administrator to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

- Open **Command Prompt** as admin
- Open services (win+R ->   services.msc)
- If u can see PostgreSQL, then unregister it.
- To Unregister the PostgreSQL,

> ```
> pg-ctl unregister [-N SERVICENAME] 
> **%path%\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_ctl unregister -N "service_name"**
> ```

*service name will be displayed on services
[image: service]